# "ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword" with sqlalchemy

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, sql-returning

Please help me figure out why the error is returned?

```
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword 
[
  SQL: INSERT INTO my_table (type_id, contact_id) 
  VALUES (:type_id, :contact_id) 
  RETURNING my_table.id, my_table.contact_id
] 
[
parameters: [
    {'type_id': 'binding_card_ma', 'contact_id': 'party_id_4'}, 
    {'type_id': 'binding_card_ma', 'contact_id': 'party_id_5'}
  ]
]
```

I use sqlalchemy, python

```
ins = f'INSERT INTO {my_table} (type_id, contact_id) ' \
f'VALUES (:type_id, :contact_id) ' \
f'RETURNING {my_table}.id, {my_table}.contact_id'

session.execute(ins, value_list)
```

It works without the RETURN instruction or with the insertion of one record, and I don't understand why

Comment: [See the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2122356) - what are you returning those values into?

Comment: You also need [`executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15): *The parameters may also be specified as list of tuples to e.g. insert multiple rows in a single operation, but this kind of usage is deprecated: .executemany() should be used instead*.